# safari 5.1.1 margin different than everything else i have tested

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, margin

i am working a a WP page and having some difficulties with what appears to be the margin on the HTML element.

it displays as expected in IE8, FF, Chrome, Mobile Safari and Opera.

this is the page in question: 
http://www.mmmf.net/2012/

i am using basically the same CSS as a site also done with WP which is:
http://www.mmmf.net/2011/

the only difference is a newer version of WP.

i placed a purple border on HTML for reference. i believe it's a 28px difference.

any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always add a yui css reset to avoid x-browser spacing issues. Do some research on it, spend the time to re-do your css with the css reset in place (place it above all other css).

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: Thanks, but WP has resets built in. The issue turned out to be my CSS setting the admin bar to hidden, but WP adjusting the top margin +28px when I was logged in.

Comment: I will let you have the answer since the problem was my idiocy.